# Merge different length arrays without losing a value using Zip()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

In the following code, I'm merging two arrays of types `int` and `string`. The first one's length is bigger than the second one, and as a result, the last index (which is `5`) doesn't get merged:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] words = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach (var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word);
}
```

I would like to know a way of getting it merged. For example, creating a `null` or empty string after the last one that exists in `words` and using it to merge with the last `numbers` index. Couldn't figure it out.

**Edit:**
Result I get

```
1one
2two
3three
4four
```

Result I want

```
1one
2two
3three
4four
5
```

Thanks!

Edit: Not a duplicate, my other question is about calling method on a null object.

Comment: I like https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/#ziplongest for this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily write your own LINQ-like extension method that will do it:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipWithDefault<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector)
    {
        bool firstMoveNext, secondMoveNext;

        using (var enum1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enum2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while ((firstMoveNext = enum1.MoveNext()) & (secondMoveNext = enum2.MoveNext()))
                yield return selector(enum1.Current, enum2.Current);

            if (firstMoveNext && !secondMoveNext)
            {
                yield return selector(enum1.Current, default(TSecond));
                while (enum1.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return selector(enum1.Current, default(TSecond));
                }
            }
            else if (!firstMoveNext && secondMoveNext)
            {
                yield return selector(default(TFirst), enum2.Current);
                while (enum2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return selector(default(TFirst), enum2.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if your source is always a pair of arrays, it might be easier to simply use `for` loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipWithDefault<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this TFirst[] first, TSecond[] second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector)
{
    var maxLength = Math.Max(first.Length, second.Length);

    for(var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        var firstItem = i < first.Length ? first[i] : default(TFirst);
        var secondItem = i < second.Length ? second[i] : default(TSecond);
        yield return selector(firstItem, secondItem);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just extend the smaller of the two collections before zipping them up, e.g. something like this:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] words = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

IEnumerable<string> wordsExtended = words;

if(words.Length < numbers.Length)
{
    wordsExtended = words.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", numbers.Length - words.Length));
}

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(wordsExtended, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach (var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word);
}
```

Ideally you want to wrap this up in a utility method and be generic so it works for any collections that are zipped.

Looks like someone wrote a generic implementation already on this [Programmers StackExchange answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/274985).

Comment: Problem with the answer you linked to is that it will cause multiple enumerations on source collection (because of `Count` call. It doesn't matter when using arrays as source, but might matter when using different sources.

Answer (score 0):

This is an asymmetric solution which uses the first sequence as an anchor, pairing corresponding elements from the second sequence when available, or a default value otherwise.   No length calculation is required, nor early forced evaluation of enumerables.

Add an extension to IEnumerable:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
        

    public static IEnumerable<T> PadRight<T>(this IEnumerable<T> s)
    {
        foreach (var t in s)
            yield return t;

        while (true)
            yield return default(T);
     }
}
```

Use the extension to "pad" the second sequence before zipping:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] words = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words.PadRight(), (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach (var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word ?? string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: This only works if you know in advance which of the inputs is shorter. And it requires that you explicitly handle that shorter input, by calling this `PadRight()` method on it. This seems like a clearly inferior solution as compared to the accepted answer. I can't imagine anyone ever opting for it over the better, more general-purpose solution. Indeed, this answer is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043952), sharing much of the same drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism.  I've incorporated your comments as a caveat.  I do point out that the proposed solution does not require forced enumeration of lazy sequences (to compute the length).  Thus it might be more efficient for some applications.

Comment: _"the proposed solution does not require forced enumeration of lazy sequences"_ -- sure, but the accepted solution does not as well, and doesn't require knowing in advance which sequence will be shorter, as yours does.

Comment: I thought this was a useful solution, under the right circumstances.