# Write columns with unequal lengths to CSV

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have deserialized a JSON file with the following data structure in C#

```
[DataContract]
public class SentimentData
{
    [DataMember(Name ="Column1")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Column1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name ="Column-2")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Count of column1 is not equal to count of column2. I just want to basically dump all data in column1 in first column and data of column2 in second column. I tried the following but not working.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv"))
{
    var nr = column1data.Select(y => new { Column1= y }).ToList();
    //var nnr = column2data.Select(y => new { Column2 = y }).ToList();

    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(nr);
    //csv.WriteRecords(nnr);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Can anyone please know how to do this?

sample json:

```
{
  "Negative": [
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt"
  ],
  "Non-Negative": [
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt",
    "a.txt",
    "b.txt"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190657/add-two-lists-of-different-length-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Nkosi i have added the sample json. i need the format as Column1 | Column2. If u see here no. of records in Column2 is bigger

Comment: @Nkosi i just empty for those columns which doesnt have data. basically jsut dump the columns

Comment: Then the link provided by @marsze looks to be your solution to build the desired object that can then be passed to the csv writer

Comment: Here is another one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043859/merge-different-length-arrays-without-losing-a-value-using-zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the a modified version of the code for the default [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2b8d0f02389aab71)

The following extension is derived to allow the zipping of collections of unequal lengths

```
public static class MyEnumerablExtensions {

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipOrDefault<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector) {
        if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
        if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("resultSelector");
        using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator()) {
            using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator()) {
                while (e1.MoveNext()) {
                    if (e2.MoveNext()) {
                        yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
                    } else {
                        yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, default(TSecond));
                    }
                }
                while (e2.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return resultSelector(default(TFirst), e2.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Error {
        public static Exception ArgumentNull(string parameter) {
            return new ArgumentNullException(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to construct the desired object model that can then be written to the CSV writer

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv")) {
    var records = column1data.ZipOrDefault(column2data, 
        (Column1, Column2) => new { Column1, Column2 });

    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try newtonsoft json.net

Install it like

```
install-package newtonsoft.json
```

This works for me:

```
static class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
            var json = "{ \"Negative\": [ \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\" ], \"Non-Negative\": [ \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\", \"a.txt\", \"b.txt\" ] }";
            var classObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public List<string> Negative { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("Non-Negative")]
   public List<string> NonNegative { get; set; }
}}
```